# ASP.NET Delegates and Expressions -Information Request

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

Based on my understanding , i interpret the meaning of Func delegate as follows.Please correct them as and when it is needed.

**`Declaration  : Func<int> dg ;`**

*1. Could i interpret it as "a Delegate
    pointing to a method that returns an
    integer?".*

**`Declaration : Func<int,int> delg1=r=>2*r;`**

*2. Could i interpret it as "  'r' is a lambda expression that itself is a   parameter of 
    an integer type being evaluated as '2 * r' and returns an int?
   .*

**`Comparison : Delegate and lambda expression`**

*3. if both Delegates and lambdas are working as function poiinters ,Where do there differ?.*

**`Comparison : Are the following two declarations  equal?`**

```
decl 1 : Func<int,int> fn=(r)=>45*r;

decl 2 : Expression<Func<int,int>> ex = (r) => r * 10;
```

*4. if both of the above mentioned constructs are serving for the same purpose ,Where do there differ?.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Yes, but it would be more precise and accurate to say "a delegate referring to a method that takes no arguments and returns an integer".

2) No. "r" is not a lambda expression. "r" is used twice, first to *declare* a formal parameter of a lambda expression, and second as part of the *body* of that lambda expression. But "r" is not the lambda expression. The lambda expression is "r=>2*r"

3) Lambdas and delegates are different things. A lambda is the abstract notion of "a function that does some thing". A delegate type is the abstract notion of the type of things which are methods that take and return certain types. A particular delegate is a reference to such a method. A lambda is *convertible* to a compatible delegate type, and if you do so, at runtime, you get a delegate instance. But a lambda is convertible to other things as well, like an expression tree.

4) They do not serve the same purpose. The expression tree is an object which *represents* the computation mentioned in the lambda. The delegate is an object which actually *performs* the computation mentioned in the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates and expressions are not the same thing.  Delegates are strongly-typed references to methods while expressions are in-memory representations of code that can be treated as data.  An expression can be compiled into IL (the [`Expression.Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) method) and this will give you a delegate to that newly compiled method.

Just remember that an expression can be turned into a delegate, but a delegate is just a delegate.